# Keep all three select elements enabled always

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I have a search box as in below

http://www.carsguide.com.au/

When I select "All new cars", the "All used cars" gets disabled. The same happens when one select "All used cars". I need all three to stay enabled always so user can chose any .

```
 $(".searchtype-option.disabled input").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
```

*I am thinking of a solution as above*

However I need it such that no matter what option is selected, the disabled tag is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about how you want to use this, but if want them to stay enabled, just don't  disable them.

However the correct jQuery code, in this particular example would be:

```
$(".searchtype-option.disabled").removeClass('disabled')
    .find('input').attr('disabled', false);
```

This will enable the input field and remove the "disabled" class from the label.